# Magento get all varient products assigned to a specific configurable product programatically

Tags: php, magento

I need to get all varient products(IDs) assigned to a specific configurable product

pls help,
THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One another better way to do the same

```
     $productsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','configurable') //load only configurable products
                ->load();

     foreach($productsCollection as $product):
     /*Get Associated Simple Products*/
      $associatedSimpleProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
      print_r($associatedSimpleProducts);
     endforeach;
```

I think this is the better one because it removes the necessity to load your product model again , as you already have that in your collection ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want all products without any filters, but it is showing only a part of the result set?

There may be several cases:

- Some inner limitation, like 100 at all.
- Some paging limitation. Products per page(in db abstract)
- Some lazyload limitation

Most of the cases, it is inner limit which restricts.

Again, found a very similar thread [***here.***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880657/magento-get-all-products) Hope this helps.

Comment: I get all configurable products by: $collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));     -- now i need to get all varient product ID's which are assigned to each of above conf. product

Comment: I Found the solution </br> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productID); </br>

$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);